# Deriving Formular for Sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, combinations

I am trying to derive a formula for the following sequence:

$a_{k}, a_{k}+a_{k}, a_{k}+a_{k}+a_{k},..., \overbrace{a_{k}+...+a_{k}}^{n}$

So the first $k$ terms of the sequence have one element, the next $k^2$ terms of the sequence are a sum of two elements, the next $k^3$ terms of the sequence are a sum of three elements and so on.

$k$ can take on any integer value between 0 and 18. $n$ can take on any value between 1 and 18.

For example assume that $k$ takes the value 1 or 2 and $n=2$. The sequence looks like this:

$a_{1}, a_{2}, a_{1}+a_{1}, a_{1}+a_{2}, a_{2}+a_{1}, a_{2}+a_{2} $

Technically in my example $a_{1}+a_{2}$ and $a_{2}+a_{1}$ are the same terms. But we can assume that these terms are different if it is easier!

Any idea how I could derive a formula so that if I plug in a value for $k$ and $n$ it would give me the corresponding term? By corresponding term I mean the composite term made up of terms from n and a. So I would like to know what the composite term is if I know what n and a equal to. For instance n=2. Hence we know there will be two a terms. Further assume the first a term takes the value 0 and the second a term takes the value 1. So the composite term is $F_{2(0,1)}=a_{0}+a_{1}$ .

Comment: There is a simple enough _procedure_ to determine the $n^{th}$ term, but I do not think there is a "formula" in the usual sense of the word (e.g. $ax^2+bx+c$). Why do you specifically need a formula?

Comment: Your example is unclear. What do you mean by $k = 1, 2$ and $n = 1, 2$? Both $k$ and $n$ are supposed to be positive integers, right? And what do you mean be *the corresponding term*?

Comment: @MikeEarnest I am writing a model in which I create a variable using two variables $a$ and $n$. $a$ can take on integer values from 0 to 18 and $n$ can take on integer values from 1 to 18. So at the end I would like to have a formula that tells me the value of my new variable if I plug in values for $a$ and $n$. The difficulty is that when $n=1$ the new variable equals $a_{k}$ where $k=0,...,18$ and when $n=2$ the new variable equals $a_{k}+a_{k}$ where $k=0,...,18$, so any combination for k e.g. $a_{0}+a_{0}$, $a_{0}+a_{1}$, $a_{0}+a_{2}$ etc. And so on until n=18 Does that make sense?

Comment: @J.-E.Pin I'm sorry for the confusion. a can take on integer values from 0 to 18 and n can take on integer values from 1 to 18. By corresponding term I mean the composite  term made up of terms from n and a. So I would like to know what the composite term is if I know what n and a equal to. For instance n=2. Hence we know there will be two a terms. Further assume the first a term takes the value 0 and the second a term takes the value 1. So the composite term is $a_{0}+a_{1}$. Does that makes sense?

Comment: You say you want "if I plug in a value for $k$ and $n$ then I get the corresponding term." But $k$ and $n$ only determine the entire sequence. To specify a term, you also need to specify the indices, e.g. the $(0,1)$ in your example. So what you need is a function that takes in $k, n$ and list of indices $(i_1,i_2,\dots,i_n)$ and returns the term $a_{i_1}+\dots+a_{i_n}$. But... that's all there is to it, the function just puts the indices in the subscript and puts $+$ signs between the $a$'s. Your question seems completely trivial.

Comment: Here's something that would be nontrivial; find a function $F(k,n,i)$ which returns the $i^{th}$ term in the list $a_1,\dots,a_k,a_1+a_1,a_1+a_2,\dots,a_k+a_K,\dots$. For example, $F(3,2,8)=a_2+a_2$, since the list for $k=3,n=2$ starts out $$a_1,a_2,a_3,a_1+a_1,a_1+a_2,a_1+a_3,a_2+a_1,a_2+a_2,\dots$$ and the $8^{th}$ element is $a_2+a_2$. Is that what you meant?

Comment: @MikeEarnest your last comment explains exactly what I meant.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't call it a formula, but there is a simple algorithm to compute the $i^{th}$ term in the sequence you describe.

1. First, find the largest number $n$ such that $k+k^2+\dots+k^{n-1}\ge i$. The required output will have $n$ terms. This part can actually be done with a formula; since $k+k^2+\dots+k^{n-1}=(k^{n}-k)/(k-1)$, we have $n=\lceil\log_k\big(k+i(k-1)\big)\rceil$.
2. Next, letting $$d=i - (k+k^2+\dots+k^{n-1}),$$compute the digits of $d$ in base $d$ in base $k$. The reason for subtracting $k+k^2+\dots+k^{n-1}$ from $i$ is to make sure the difference $d$ has $n$ or fewer digits in base $k$. Letting these digits be $[d_{n-1},d_{n-2},\cdots ,d_0]$ (possibly allowing leading zeroes), we also have the formulae
   $$
   d_0 = d\!\!\!\!\mod k,\qquad 
   d_1 =\left\lfloor d\over k\right\rfloor\hspace{-.4cm}\mod{k},
   \quad\dots\quad 
   d_{n-1}=\left\lfloor d\over k^{n-1}\right\rfloor\hspace{-.4cm}\mod{k}
   $$
   These digits are in the range $\{0,1,\dots,k-1\}$. If you instead want the subscripts to be in the range $\{1,2,\dots,k\}$, then you also need to add one to each of these digits.
3. Finally, put the numbers $d_{n-1},d_{n-2},\dots,d_{1},d_0$ into the subscripts of the expression $$\overbrace{a_{\bullet}+a_\bullet+\dots+a_\bullet}^{\text{$n$ terms}}$$ so that $d_{n-1}$ is on the left and $d_{0}$ is on the right, and there you have it!